# Adding number to variable name

Tags: vba

I want to write a macro for iGrafx which will check how many objects is in created by user model and check their type (ex. line, block etc.). To do this in wrote simple loop but my problem is -- iGrafx objects have names Shape1, Shape2 or Line1, Line2, how can I write loop in which I can use TypeOf and add to variable name Shape a number every time it loops?

```
Dim numObjects As Integer                              
Dim numObjectsArraySize As Integer
Dim procesObjectsTypes() As String
Dim index As Integer
Dim loopVarName As String
Dim indexString As String

numObjects = Document.ActiveDiagram.DiagramObjects.Count  
numObjectsArraySize = numObjects - 1                        

ReDim procesObjectsTypes(numObjectsArraySize)    

For index = 1 To numObjects
    indexString = CStr(index)
    loopVarName = "Shape" + indexString
    procesObjectsTypes(index - 1) = TypeName(loopVarName)
Next
```

Comment: Checking of loopVarName value gives String which is normal, but I want to use that string inside that variable as a variable name to check its type.

Comment: This is almost certainly not the right way. I'm not familiar with iGrafx, but if you show us how you *create* an object (e.g. `Shape1`) then it may be possible to help.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Shapes are created by user in program using GUI. My goal is to write a macro to export all the data and info that model created by 'drag and drop' includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a punt as I've never used iGrafx before; if they have stuck to object model conventions established in Word VBA and Excel VBA then I am guessing that the DiagramObjects collection has an Item method.

```
procesObjectsTypes(index - 1) = TypeName(Document.ActiveDiagram.DiagramObjects.Item(index)) & indexString
```

Comment: I've finally found it and from now my base is your idea about DiagramObjects objectivity. Thanks :)